# How do I see ALL the versions of a package on NPM?

Tags: npm, version, package-managers

I've been using `bower info package` and `npm view package` to see which package manager has more versions of numerous packages and have found that bower goes much farther back to older versions of the packages. Do old verions simply 'expire' on npm and cannot be installed through npm after a period of type? Or is there a way for me to see older versions?

Comment: Packages do not expire. Maybe those versions have simply never been published to the npm registry? Maybe they have since been removed by their authors?

Comment: that's strange that those packages have not been removed on bower though